# Codeigniter cache page

Tags: codeigniter, session, caching, architecture

I have a site developed in codeigniter.
In the page search I have a form that when I compile It I send a request to a servere with CURL and return me an xml.
This query and the print date is about 15seconds because I have to make more query with many server and this time is necessary.
But the problem is: I have a list of element, when I click on an element I make a query to retrieve the data of the element.
But if I click back or click to go back to all element searched I don't want to make an other query that takes 15second.

When I search the element I have a get request and I have a link like this:

```
http://myurl/backend/hotel/hotel_list?nation=94&city=1007&check-in=12%2FApr%2F2013&check-out=13%2FApr%2F2013&n_single_rooms=1&n_double_rooms=0&n_triple_rooms=0&n_extra_beds=0
```

I load the page and I can have more elements. i click on some of this in a simple link like this:

```
http://myurl/backend/hotel/hotel_view?id_service=tra_0_YYW
```

When I enter into this page I have to go back to the previous url (the first) without remake the query that takes more seconds.
I can't cache the result because is a realtime database and change every minutes or second but I thinked to cache the page search when I enter on it and if i go back to it reload from cache if the time is minor than 2 minutes for example.
Is this a good way or there is a more perfmormant way to do this in codeigniter?
I can't put in session because there is large data.

The other solution are:
- cache page (but every minutes I have to delete it)
- cache result (but every minutes I have to delete it)
- create sessionflashdata (but I have a large amount of data)

is there a way with the browser when I go back to don't remake the page?

Thanks

Comment: using db session you can easly enter huge data, just use it with TEXT field for userdata nope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- cache page (but every minutes I have to delete it)

I think you can easily implement it with codeigniter's page caching function "$this->output->cache(1);"

- cache result (but every minutes I have to delete it)
  You will have to use codeigniter's object caching method to implement it.
- create sessionflashdata (but I have a large amount of data)
  Its not a good idea to save huge data in session. Rather use 'database session' instead, which will help you handling similar way and codeigniter has its integrated support.

Hope this helps. You can read more about [all kind of codeigniter caching](http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-caching-tutorial-php) if you are just starting with it.